# (Mechanics/Electronics) Anybody know DTC code for asking Air flow measurement on OBD2?

Tags: electronics

(Sorry if there's a better place for this. It's my first question)

I'm doing a final work for a Bachelor in Electronics and my work consists in making a fuel meter for a car. Its connected via OBD2 port using CAN protocol.

My problem is i can't seem to find anywhere how to ask for the Mass Air Flow (MAF). The only thing i found was trouble codes eg. faulty MAF or so.

Any help is really apreciated, as im running out of time for my project and i've found little information so far.